# Input type doesn't center

Tags: html, css, web

I was practising some code and then this happened, The input text tag won't center. Margin: 0 auto; also doesn't seem to work either.

Here's the code I was working on.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Email">
```

**CSS:**

```
input {
outline: none;
border-radius: 5px;
border-style: none;
height: 45px;
width: 218px;
padding:0 16px;
font-family: Helvetica Neue;  
font-size: 18px;
background-color: rgb(250,250,250);
margin:0 auto;
}
```

Can anyone help me out with this? and also a possible explanation?

Comment: `text-align: center;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**try using display:block in input element**

snippet

```css
div{
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
  border:solid;
}
input {
display:block;
outline: none;
border-radius: 5px;
border-style: none;
height: 45px;
width: 218px;
padding:0 16px;
font-family: Helvetica Neue;  
font-size: 18px;
background-color: rgb(250,250,250);
margin:0 auto;
border:solid;
}
```

```html
<div>
<input type="text" placeholder="Email">
</div>
```

Comment: It works, But why not display it as an inline-block?

Comment: apparently this has no effect on input elements as indicated on snippet..but you can put input tag in a div and use text-align:center .in div css styling .:D

Comment: Yep that's how I was doing, Putting the `<input>` inside a `<p>` . But that isn't the proper way, isn't it.

Comment: There are  several solutions..work with the solution  which you feel comfortable with and meets the occasion..

Answer (score 1):

```
input {
        display:block;
         margin:0 auto;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
input {
text-align:center;
}
```

[click here](https://jsfiddle.net/2ahqa69d/) for demo

Comment: That won't work. It will only center the placeholder inside the text field. I need the field itself to be centered.

Comment: Figured it out! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<style>
    input {
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-style: none;
    height: 45px;
    width: 218px;
    padding:0 16px;
    font-family: Helvetica Neue;  
    font-size: 18px;
    background-color: rgb(250,250,250);
    position:absolute;
    left:300px;
  }

</style>
</head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Email">
    </body>
</html>
```

*just increase the left px where you want it.

Comment: That isn't healthy, It needs to be centered automatically according to the width of the browser, I figured it out. Displaying it as a block element and then specifying it a `margin: 0 auto;` did the trick.